# Word for a physicist studying mechanics?

Tags: single-word-requests, science

For many fields there is a word for a person studying it. In math there is analyst for analysis, algebraist for algebra, and geometer for geometry.

Is there an equivalent word for a physicist studying mechanics?

Comment: Sounds like a question for [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *mechanician*, apparently, although some dictionaries such as [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mechanician) restrict the meaning of the word to "someone who works with machines or makes them".

Comment: You need to give a supporting reference in an ELU answer, not a mitigation. Lexico only gives the philosophical sense here.